# jcl104-over-slf4j version 1.4.2 is safe to be replaced by jcl-over-slf4j 1.7.2

Tags: log4j, slf4j

This is an informational post just to help out if u came across such issue.

My old struts application depends on displaytag 1.2 version. This display tag is resolving transitive a dependency on jcl104-over-slf4j 1.4.2 version. I did some investigation and found out that

> June 5th, 2008 - Release of SLF4J 1.5.1
>   http://www.slf4j.org/news.html
>   See also the compatibility report for this version.
>   In order to support JCL version 1.1.1, the jcl104-over-slf4j module was renamed as jcl-over-slf4j. SLF4J will no longer ship with jcl104-over-slf4j.jar but with jcl-over-slf4j.jar. The related work responds to enhancement request discussed in bug 85 as reported by Niklas Gustavsson.

I tested my application it seems to be working. I cannot find the bug-85 details reported on the site(http://www.slf4j.org/news.html). But didn't came across any side effects.

If your application is also using jcl-over-slf4j updated version explicitly it will cause following exception depending upon which jar is loaded first.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org/slf4j/spi/LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing changed between `jcl104-over-slf4j` and `jcl-over-slf4j` except the name of the artifact. In other words, you can safely replace `jcl104-over-slf4j` and `jcl-over-slf4j`.

However, make to sure to match the version of `jcl-over-slf4j` and that of `slf4j-api` as well as the binding you are using, e.g. slf4j-simple, slf4j-log4j12 or logback.